# How to add a "viewDidLoad" kind of method to a UIImageView subclass?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to add a gesture recognizer to a class called "MenuItem", which is a subclass of UIImageView.

I'm using Storyboard to lay out the locations of my UIImageViews, and then assigning their class to MenuItem. Rather than add a UIPanGestureRecognizer on each MenuItem through Storyboard, I'd rather do it in code.

So I guess I kind of what to add some sort of "viewDidLoad" class to my MenuItem, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want to add the recognizers in the UIView's appropriate init method. In this case, you are creating them from within InterfaceBuilder, so the appropriate method to override would be:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // add gesture recognizers
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work if the gesture recognizer needs to invoke a method on the view controller.

Comment: In the case where the parent view controller handles the action, you could just add some code in viewDidLoad to search for all instances of MenuItem and add the recognizer. This assumes of course, that the action method is the same for each MenuItem.

Comment: This works fine for my code. I originally did what you just mentioned, I used a for loop in viewDidLoad to find instances of MenuItem in my ViewController subview and then ran a setup method on each. 

initWithCoder however is much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkAdams - why is that? I am running into that scenario